# Data Update in Table after applied NLP

Tags: python, nlp

Let's assume I have a table called `keywords_test`.

It consists of the following fields (with sample records):

| db_id | type | object_id | keyword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1200 | BusinessOrgID |

The script below is used for processing keywords. For example, it turns "BusinessOrgID" into "business organization id." In the script below, as you can see, I used SELECT keyword from keywords_test. This works well. However, I'm not sure how to send the data back to the table in such a way that "object_id" and other fields match. For example, our record should be updated as follows:

| db_id | type | object_id | keyword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1200 | business organization id |

And if I were to add logic to the script responsible for creating additional keywords, it should create several records with the same object_id, such as:

| db_id | type | object_id | keyword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1200 | business organization id |
| 1 | a | 1200 | business |
| 1 | a | 1200 | organization id |
| 1 | a | 1200 | business id |

**Text Processing Script:**

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import pyodbc
import csv
import wordninja
import re


# Loading Environment Variables
load_dotenv('.env')
db_user = os.getenv('USER')
db_password = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
db_host = os.getenv('HOST')
db_name = os.getenv('DB_NAME')

# Creating Connection String
connection_string = f"DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER={db_host};DATABASE={db_name};UID={db_user};PWD={db_password}"

# Connecting to the Database
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Retrieving Keywords from the Database
cursor.execute('SELECT keyword FROM keywords_test')
rows = cursor.fetchall()

# Abbreviation Definitions
abbreviations = {
    "dwh": "data warehouse",
    "attr": "attribute",
    ...
}

# List of words to be protected from splitting
protected_words = list(set(["id", "emails", "update", "msdyn"...])) 

def split_protected_and_compounds(text):
    for protected in protected_words:
        matches = re.finditer(protected, text, re.IGNORECASE)
        # Create a list of positions where protected words occur
        protected_ranges = [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in matches]

        result = []
        start_index = 0

        for prange in protected_ranges:
            # Add words from the last index to the beginning of the protected word
            if start_index != prange[0]:
                segment = text[start_index:prange[0]]
                result.extend(wordninja.split(segment))
            
            # Add the protected word
            result.append(text[prange[0]:prange[1]])
            
            start_index = prange[1]
        
        # Add the remaining text after the last protected word
        result.extend(wordninja.split(text[start_index:]))

        return ' '.join(result)


def expand_abbreviations(text):
    words = text.split()
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        if word in abbreviations:
            new_words.extend(abbreviations[word].split())
        else:
            new_words.append(word)
    return ' '.join(new_words)

def split_custom_compounds(text):
    split_pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|[_-]')
    return ' '.join(re.split(split_pattern, text))

def process_text(keyword):
    keyword = split_custom_compounds(keyword)
    keyword = keyword.lower()
    keyword = expand_abbreviations(keyword)
    keyword = split_protected_and_compounds(keyword)
    keyword = expand_abbreviations(keyword)
    keyword = ' '.join([word for word in keyword.split() if len(word) > 1])
    return keyword

processed_keywords = [process_text(row[0]) for row in rows]

# Save to csv
filename = 'processed_keywords.csv'
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["Processed Keyword"]) 
    for keyword in processed_keywords:
        writer.writerow([keyword]) 

# Closing the Database Connection
conn.close()
```

As you can see, I'm fetching data here using a simple query: `cursor.execute('SELECT keyword FROM keywords_test')`.

However, I'm not sure how to update this database. It would be best to do it in some meaningful flow.

I tried with a temp table but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you reading and updating the same table? If you insert new records into the same table as a result of this update, how should they be factored into the logic of processing the table to avoid recursively adding infinite records? Is this table small enough to process all rows in a single transaction or even load them all into memory at once?

Comment: As you can see, it does not update the table. The current solution simply processes "keywords" and saves the results to a CSV file. I would like to update the table or create a new rule as exactly as described in the question. The table is not large, it contains about 150,000 records

Comment: Sorry, that is probably a good idea.  I assumed it did based on the layout of the table in your post.  Let me take a closer look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by fetching all the columns of the table. If you just want those specific ones you can name them delimited by commas as well.

So rather than:

```py
# Retrieving Keywords from the Database
cursor.execute('SELECT keyword FROM keywords_test')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

We will do:

```py
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM keywords_test')
table_columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
rows = [dict(zip(table_columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Then when we go to update we will process the given attribute of the dictionary rather than the item of the list.

Rather than:

```py
processed_keywords = [process_text(row[0]) for row in rows]
```

We will:

```py
for row in rows:
    row["keyword"] = process_text(row["keyword"])
```

Then that just leaves us to write the csv with that list of dictionaries:

rather than:

```py
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["Processed Keyword"]) 
    for keyword in processed_keywords:
        writer.writerow([keyword])
```

something like:

```py
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=list(rows[0].keys()))
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Cool! it works, thank you! I just had to change the line: `writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=list(rows[0].keys))` to:   `writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=list(rows[0].keys()))`

Comment: Is it possible to update the table from which we retrieved data in the same script instead of saving it to a CSV file? So, we retrieve: `'SELECT * FROM keywords_test'`, process the "keyword" column, and then perform an update on that table instead of save it to csv?

Comment: oops, let me edit that here as well

Comment: sure, assuming that `db_id` was the primary key, one could iterate rows and inside do a "UPDATE TABLE keywords_test SET keyword = ? WHERE db_id = ?" passing in the parameters `(row[keyword ], row["db_id"])`.  Something like that. I always have to look up the particular SQL parameter placeholder so this is just from memory

Comment: This sort of solves my problem. However, I need to update the table (which is not that easy as we are getting more records). I'll post a separate question for that

Comment: I also added a question about updating this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053059/update-table-in-sql-server-after-processing-records-in-python

Comment: I'll take a look when I get to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77058436/update-data-in-a-table-after-processing-it-with-nlp